# Integrating $1/(1+exp(ax))^b$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a problem with integrating

$1/(1+exp(-ax))^b (a,B>0)$

partial integration doesn't really work here, but I am unable to find the proper substitution. The transformation that we would use for integrating

$$\frac1{1+\exp(-ax)}=\frac{\exp(ax)}{\exp(ax)+1}=\frac d{dX} \log(\exp(ax)+1)$$

is not of help here either.

Comment: According to Alpha, the antiderivative involves the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$. Is that suitable?

Comment: Mathjax use would allow more people to help you with your question, especially those from mobile phones.

Comment: The substitution $-u=\exp(-ax)$ quickly transforms the integral to one very close to the definition of the incomplete beta function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function